# What do Teignmouth, Paris, Ulm, Auxerre, Brunswick, Beaumont-en-Auge, and Ryazan have in common?

Tags: knowledge, geography, history

In the book [*Real World Haskell*](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Real-World-Haskell-Bryan-OSullivan/dp/0596514980), there's a non-programming-related puzzle in a footnote at the bottom of page 15, in the middle of a simple text-processing problem:

> ...
>
> Find or create a text file; let's call it *quux.txt*:*
>
> ```
> $ cat quux.txt
> Teignmouth, England
> Paris, France
> Ulm, Germany
> Auxerre, France
> Brunswick, Germany
> Beaumont-en-Auge, France
> Ryazan, Russia
> ```
>
> ...
>
> * Incidentally, what do these cities have in common?

While I hope my abilities will prove sufficient to solve the book's programming problems, this little geography puzzle is beyond me. What *do* these seven cities have in common?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Interestingly, this puzzle has little to do with geography and more to do with science! These cities and towns are:

> The birthplaces of famous mathematicians (and scientists), each of whom is frequently considered among the greatest in world history.

As follows:

> Charles Babbage, b. 1791/2 in **Teignmouth, England** (although some sources argue he was born in London)
>
>  Augustin-Louis Cauchy, b. 1789 in **Paris, France**
>
>  Albert Einstein, b. 1879 in **Ulm, Germany**
>
>  Jean-Baptiste Joseph Fourier, b. 1768 in **Auxerre, France**
>
>  Carl Friedrich Gauss, b. 1777 in **Brunswick, Germany**
>
>  Pierre-Simon Laplace, b. 1749 in **Beaumont-en-Auge, France**
>
>  Andrey Andreyevich Markov, b. 1856 in **Ryazan, Russia**

Comment: Off-the-point, but then why call the file 'quux'? (if you know!)

Comment: @JonMarkPerry Yes, 'quux' is just another equivalent of 'foo' or 'bar' often used by programmers when naming something which doesn't particularly require a meaningful name. It's a placeholder, nothing more, and unconnected with the puzzle itself :)

Comment: For what it's worth, 'quux' is canonically the _fourth_ placeholder, following 'foo', 'bar', and 'baz'.

Comment: And it's ordered alphabetically by (spoiler) and cut off for some reason at M; otherwise Woolsthorpe-by-Colsterworth, England would be next.